# How to hide the rest of the contents using simple CSS and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is very simple. I want to display only the content of one tr at a time. That means when I click on the other tr then the other opened tr should get closed.

My code is as below

```
<head>

    <style>
      p { width:400px; }
      .click{cursor:pointer;}
    </style>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    function visibility(id) {

        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'block';
        else
          e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

Above is the head section where onClick a function called visibility is getting called. Below in the body section I am trying to display two tr using for loop.

```
<body>
<table>
<?php
$i=2;
for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
?>
    <tr class="click <?php echo $i; ?>" onClick="visibility('<?php echo $i; ?>');">
        <td>Click <?php echo $i; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;">
        <td>This is a paragraph <?php echo $i; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</body>
```

I am unable to get the desired result(That means only one tr should be visible at a time). There are many existing Jquery plugins available but I do not want to use them as it will increase the load on my web page and so much of customization will be required. I am almost done and hoping to get the desired result with the help from you all. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two rows for each loop ... Which you want to show...??

Comment: Say I have two rows 1 and 2. If I am clicking on 1 then it should show the content of 1 and when I am clicking on 2 then it should show the content of 2. Its happening very properly at the moment. To hide the previously opened row, I've to click on that particular row. But I want it to get hidden as soon as I click on the other row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a `click` handler to your `tr.click` elements, show the corresponding content, and hide the others:

```
$(this).next('tr').show().siblings().not('tr.click').hide();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ4fG/2/)

Comment: That is much shorter than my solution :)

Comment: Hi Billyonecan, I'll just try out your code. I think it should give me my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the display to `table-row` value when displaying the "tr" element.
Let's make use of jQuery.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.clickablerows', function() {
     $('.showablerows').css('display','none');
     var showee = $(this).data('showee');
     $(showee).css('display','table-row');
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. can you give me one small example please.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add/remove a class and handle the visibility state through that so you have more control over what happens with the active/inactive elements (plus you don't have to care if one of the siblings is the clicked element). Also you can use the event delegation of `.on()` to save some time attaching the event handler.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ4fG/3/)

**JS**

```
var activeClass = 'active';

$('table').on('click', '.click', function() {
   $(this).next().addClass(activeClass).siblings().removeClass(activeClass);
});
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    display: none;
}

.active td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first set class name "test" for all td's

then use this code

$(".test").click(function(){

$(".test").hide();
 $(this).show();

});